# Only allowing merges from a certain branch?

Tags: git

Consider a following branch setup:

- production branch
- qa branch
- staging branch
- several development branches

Is there a way to only allow merging from a specific branch, for example allow the production branch to only accept merges from qa branch, but reject merges from staging/development branches?

The goal would be to ensure only the things that have gone through a certain branch and its associated workflow end up in the production branch and use git to further enforce this.

Comment: I guess this lies outside the scope of pure Git and is the domain of code review tools like Gerrit.

Comment: @LarsNoschinski, still hooks might handle this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your developers push to a central repository, you can install an `update` hook to enforce your policy:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

log() { printf %s\\n "$*"; }
error() { log "ERROR: $@" >&2; }
fatal() { error "$@"; exit 1; }

REF=$1
OLD=$2
NEW=$3

# ignore refs being deleted or created
case 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 in
    "${NEW}"|"${OLD}") exit 0;;
esac

case ${REF} in
    refs/heads/production)
        git rev-list --no-merges "${OLD}".."${NEW}" |
        while IFS= read -r rev; do
            git merge-base --is-ancestor "${rev}" refs/heads/qa \
                || fatal "${rev} must be merged to qa\
 before it can be merged to production"
        done
        ;;
esac
```

(The above hook has not been tested at all.  Let me know if you encounter any problems with it.)